# A method that insert an element at a certain position in a stack. (java)

Tags: java, list, stack

I am trying to code in stacks and I am implementing various methods in it. I am trying a method named `insertAtPos(int value, int pos)` where I insert a `value` at position `pos`. Is this even possible?

I am getting as a result the initial stack. I'm not understanding where is the error.

This is the method (my approach):

```
public void insertAtPos(int pos, int value) {  //////////?????
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        int c = 0;
        
        while(!this.isEmpty() && c != pos) {
            s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
            c++;
            
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
            
        }
        
    }
```

And this is the whole class:

```
public class Stack {
    class Element{
        int data;
        Element next = null;
        
        Element(int value){
            data = value;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    
    private Element head = null;
    
    public Stack() {
        head = null;
    }
    
    
    public static void display(Stack s) {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("the stack is empty");
            return;
        }
        
        while(!s.isEmpty()) {
            
            s1.push(s.stackTop());
            s.pop();
            System.out.println(s1.stackTop());
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            s.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.head == null;
    }
    
    public void push(int value) {
        Element tmp = new Element(value);
        tmp.next = head;
        head = tmp;
        
    }
    
    public int pop() {
        if(isEmpty())
            System.exit(1);
        head = head.next;
    return 1;
    }
    
    public int stackTop() {
        if(isEmpty())
            System.exit(2);
        return head.data;
    }
    
    public void makeEmpty() {
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            this.pop();
        }
    }
    
    public int stackTopAndPop(){
        this.pop();
        return this.stackTop();
    }
    
    public int search(int value) { 
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        int index = -1;
        int c = 0; //counter
        
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("the stack is empty");
            return -1;
        }
        
        while(!this.isEmpty() && index == -1) {
            if(this.stackTop() == value)
                index = c;
            s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
            c++;
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        return index;
    }
    
    
    public int count() {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        int c = 0; // counter
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
            c++;
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public void insertNoRepetition(int value) {  //////////?????
        
    }
    
    
    public void insertAtPos(int pos, int value) {  //////////?????
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        int c = 0;
        
        while(!this.isEmpty() && c != pos) {
            s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
            c++;
            
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public void delete(int value) {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() != value)
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    public void deleteFirstOccurence(int value) {   //////////?????
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() != value) {
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
                return;
            }
            this.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public void deleteEven() {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() % 2 != 0)
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public void deleteOdd() {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() % 2 == 0)
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public void deletePositive() {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() < 0)
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
    
    
    public void deleteLessOrEqualThan(int value) {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.stackTop() > value)
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
            this.pop();
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
        }
        
    }
    
    
    //delete all elements = to the elements stored in another stack
    public void deleteEqualToOther(Stack s) {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        Stack s2 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty() && this.stackTop() == s.stackTop()) {
            
                s1.push(this.stackTop());
                
            this.pop();
            
        }
        
        while(!s1.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(s1.stackTop());
            s1.pop();
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
//  public Stack union(Stack s1, Stack s2) {
//      
//  }
//  
//  
//  public Stack intersection(Stack s1, Stack s2) {
//      
//  }
    
    
    public Stack ascendingOrder() {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            int tmp = this.pop();
            
            while(!s1.isEmpty() && s1.stackTop() > tmp) {
                this.push(s1.stackTop());
                s1.pop();
            }
            
            s1.push(tmp);
        }
        return s1;
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack s1 = new Stack();
//      Stack s2 = new Stack();
        
        s1.push(1);
        s1.push(3);
        s1.push(3);
        s1.push(4);
        s1.push(-5);
        display(s1);
        System.out.println("______________________");
        
//      s2.push(1);
//      s2.push(3);
//      s2.push(4);
//      s2.push(6);
//      s2.push(7);
//      display(s2);
//      System.out.println("______________________");

        
//      System.out.println(s1.search(3));
//      System.out.println("______________________");
//
//      System.out.println(s1.count());
//      System.out.println("______________________");
//      
//      s1.delete(2);
//      display(s1);
//      System.out.println("______________________");

//      System.out.println(s1.stackTop());
//      System.out.println("______________________");
        
//      s1.makeEmpty();
//      display(s1);
//      System.out.println("______________________");
        
//      s1.deleteLessOrEqualThan(2);
//      display(s1);
//      System.out.println("______________________");
        
//      s1.deleteEqualToOther(s2);
//      display(s1);
//      System.out.println("______________________");

        
//      s1.ascendingOrder();
//      display(s1);
//      System.out.println("______________________");

        
//      s1.deleteFirstOccurence(3);
//      display(s1);
//      System.out.println("______________________");
        
        s1.insertAtPos(2, 2);
        display(s1);

        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting as a result the initial stack because you never push the "value" in method "insertAtPos".

And yes, it is possible inside your stack implementation. But it doesn't make any sense for you to try to insert an element in an internal position of the stack. That breaks the LIFO "Last In, First Out" restriction. If you want to do it for coding learning purposes it's OK, but a real implementation of a stack should not include that function.

Comment: I know the LIFO restriction, but isn't it possible to pop all values until a certain position, then push the popped values back. Does this still breaks the LIFO restriction?

Comment: If you put that method inside the stack implementation (as a functionality of the stack) it breaks the restriction. You can do that from the client that uses your stack. If you want that your code works you only need to add: 
this.push(value);
between the two switches of insertAtPos function.